# Which is the best GUI tool for J2ME apps

Tags: user-interface, graphics, java-me, look-and-feel, j2mepolish

I am doing a commercial j2me project in which I need some good Gui like tabbed pane and auto complete text boxes and I need a constant look and feel across all handsets so anyone having idea what gui tool used for commercial apps. I found j2me polish and LWUIT but I m confused which is preferred in j2me commercial apps.

Answer (score 3):

There is no stand out choice when it comes to J2ME GUI frameworks. It really depends on the requirements of your project and what fits best.

I have used a commercial framework from Paxmodept, which worked well and included the source code. In addition to J2ME Polish and LWUIT there are a couple notable open source alternatives:

- J4ME looks decent and importantly has active development.
- Fire allows you to specify the look and feel using xHTML & CSS and also has active development.

For the open source frameworks, download the source code and create simple hello world apps. It shouldn't take long and will give you some insight into the pros and cons of each framework.

If you do use a commercial framework it is important that you have access to the source code as you'll most likely need to make small changes to fit the exact needs of your project.

Comment: J4ME has limited number of components to be useful for any decent commercial project. Yes, I have very positive experiences with J2ME Polish and Fire; I second them

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is definitely LWUIT. LWUIT stands for Light Weight User Interface Toolkit and I must tell you its awesome! I am using it to develop some apps at work and it fits the bill: uniform look across platforms, works the same way on BB, Samsung, Nokia and Windows Mobile[not tested Windows personally though]. The latest version also allows you to embed HTML and CSS and best of all its Open source!
Enjoy!

Comment: My experience with LWUIT was a bit negative; I felt it's bloated and too sluggish to work on. Do you have any "optimization" secrets to work a bit oldish phones?

Comment: Well, all arguments apply to J2ME-Polish, too. (Except that you need a license for commercial apps). The app will look quiet uniform on most devices, they have BB support, Windows Mobile with J2ME, and you can style (mostly) everything with css.